# The camera displays a stretched image

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-camera, textures

I have that code:

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: deviceRatio,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomPaint(
              foregroundPainter: MeasureFaceOutline(isPosCorrect: true),
              child: Transform(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                transform: Platform.isIOS ? Matrix4.rotationX(math.pi) : Matrix4.identity(),
                child: Texture(textureId: textureId),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And my view from camera is very **stretched**. How can I set ratio (or transform) for display camera view **without stretched**?

EDIT:
If I use CameraPreview like that:

```
Transform.scale(
                scale: 1.7,
                child: Center(
                  child: CameraPreview(controller!),
                ),
              )
```

everything is okay, but I have to use *Texture* instead *CameraPreview*

Comment: I believe the problem is the underlaying texture is returning the fixed size which you are somehow stretching. You can try using `BoxFit` or have the calculation on native side to see how much size the texture should have there.

Comment: Still I don't know how can I calculate that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FractionallySizedBox which will scale to your container

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: 1.0,
  widthFactor: 1.0,
  child: ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scale using `Matrix4.diagonal3Values` for scaling, since you can control the `X`, `Y`, `Z axis`. `X` is the `horizontal`, `Y` is the `vertical` and `Z` is for those going into other dimensions

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
final xScale = cameraController.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio;
// Modify the yScale if you are in Landscape
final yScale = 1;


return Container(
  child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: deviceRatio,
        child: Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(xScale, yScale, 1),
          child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Check this out [Making a camera application in Flutter](https://medium.com/lightsnap/making-a-full-screen-camera-application-in-flutter-65db7f5d717b)